# Why is a div returned by a websocket not animated in htmx framwork?

Tags: htmx

Using the htmx framework, I want a soft color change for the element returned by a websocket connection. The color animation works for the div returned for the GET request, but not for the div returned by the websocket connection.

Does this code miss some attributes?

Here is a reduced code example, which demostrates the issue.
(The "#tst" div is animated, the "#tstws" div changes colors instantly)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/ws.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tst" style="color: red; transition: color 2s ease-out;" hx-get="/tst" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="every 2s">test color-animation</div>
    <div hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws"></div>
    <div id="tstws" style="color: red; transition: color 2s ease-out;">test ws color-animation</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The GET for "/tst" returns (results in an animated color):

```
f'<div id="tst" style="color: {col[idx]}; transition: color 2s ease-out;" hx-get="/tst" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="every 2s">test color-animation</div>'
```

The websocket sends (results in color instantly changed on swap):

```
f'<div id="tstws" style="color: {col[idx]}; transition: color 2s ease-out;">test ws color-animation</div>'
```

The documentation for the websocket has no additional hints for a special handling of animations/transitions:
https://htmx.org/extensions/web-sockets/

The animation section does not have any hits for swaps websockets:
https://htmx.org/examples/animations/